# CircleCI start running steps in parallel after number of steps

Tags: phpunit, circleci, circleci-2.0

I have a `config.yaml` for my CirleCI workflow.

I use PHPUnit to run my tests but I would like to start running these in parallel using Circle to speed up the deploy process.

So `BuildJob` looks like this:

```
jobs:
  #  build-job
  build-job:
    <<: *defaults  
    resource_class: large
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: sudo apt install -y libsqlite3-dev zlib1g-dev libpng-dev libxml2-dev
      - run: sudo docker-php-ext-install zip
      - run: sudo docker-php-ext-install gd
      - run: sudo docker-php-ext-install soap
      - run: sudo docker-php-ext-install bcmath
      - run: sudo composer self-update
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - composer-v1-{{ checksum "composer.lock" }}
            - composer-v1-
      - run: composer install -n --prefer-dist
      - save_cache:
          key: composer-v1-{{ checksum "composer.lock" }}
          paths:
            - vendor
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - node-v1-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            - node-v1-
      - run: 
          name: Create sqlite db
          command: touch database/database.sqlite
      - run: 
          name: Run tests
          command: ./vendor/bin/phpunit -d memory_limit=512M
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: ~/laravel
          paths: .
```

So I know I need to add `parallelism: 4` into there before the steps to run them in parallel, as documented [here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/parallelism-faster-jobs/) but I need the steps up to `Run tests` in order. Then I will have multiple run tests steps to hit each folder of tests.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: First off, `parallelism` is not necessary. You just need to define multiple jobs (you only have the one `build-job`) and split up the testing scope of phpunit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach of using the CircleCI CLI command `circleci tests split` to split the tests up for parallel containers does not work with phpunit, according to this discussion (https://discuss.circleci.com/t/how-to-execute-phpunit-tests-in-parallel/25622). However, as @matfax is saying, can you run the tests in several logical groups? Something like

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/ThisGroup
./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/ThatGroup
```

If so, you could then run each of those commands in a parallel job within a CircleCI workflow.

Comment: Trouble is running those first parts, I think I need a couple jobs, one to set up and one to run the tests in parallel

Comment: One to set up (and save workspace), then multiple to run tests in parallel (with attached workspace) I think.

Comment: You should not attempt to use workspace for tools installed with apt-get, etc.  Instead consider a single job that adds these to a custom docker image that downstream jobs can use.

To make builds even faster, consider a separate project/repo to build your PHP image as needed, and reference that in you jobs.

Comment: This answer does not address the question at hand, which is "how do I run some steps in parallel but not others?"